# Is msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed a "hidden" member?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Using the following commands does not produce a member named `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed`. Is this some type of "hidden" member? Are there other "hidden" members of objects?

```
Get-ADUser -identity $Env:USERNAME –Properties *
Get-ADUser -identity $Env:USERNAME –Properties * | Format-List -Property * -Force
```

However, the value of `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` is produced by the following command.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $Env:USERNAME –Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"
```

It can be used to calculate the user account password expiration date.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $Env:USERNAME –Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |
Select-Object -Property "Displayname",@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
```

It occurs on both PowerShell Core and Windows PowerShell.

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.2.6
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
5.1.19041.1682
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that [`msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/f9e9b7e2-c7ac-4db6-ba38-71d9696981e9) is a [`Constructed` attribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/a3aff238-5f0e-4eec-8598-0a59c30ecd56) type that is not static but calculated/computed to get the value.

**The theory is** that since it's a calculated value, it's more resource intense to enumerate the value per computational overhead. For performance reasons, ***by default*** `Get-ADUser` does not enumerate all the calculated attributes with the wildcard `-Properties *` parameter as was used.[<sup>[1]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332818/get-aduser-not-returning-all-possible-ad-attributes-when-specifying-all-properti)

[<sub>Source reference per above conclusion <sup>[1]</sup></sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332818/get-aduser-not-returning-all-possible-ad-attributes-when-specifying-all-properti)

**The solution is** to explicitly specify one of the `Constructed` attribute property values in conjunction with the `-Properties *` wildcard as per the below example PowerShell.

However, from what I can tell, if you name one of those explicitly, some of the other `Constructed` attribute property values will enumerate ***but not necessarily all of them***.

This means if expected attributes are not output, then add those explicitly too comma separated before the comma asterisk [`, *`]. (e.g. `Get-ADUser -Identity $Env:USERNAME –Properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed, ModifyTimeStamp, * | Format-List * -Force;`).

### PowerShell

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $Env:USERNAME –Properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed, * | Format-List * -Force;
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-ADUser not returning all possible AD attributes when specifying all properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332818/get-aduser-not-returning-all-possible-ad-attributes-when-specifying-all-properti)
- [3.1.1.4.5 Constructed Attributes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/a3aff238-5f0e-4eec-8598-0a59c30ecd56)
- [3.1.1.4.5.33 msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/f9e9b7e2-c7ac-4db6-ba38-71d9696981e9)

Comment: Good info, but the sample output in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76485174/45375) suggests that naming _one_ constructed attribute retrieves _only that_, not also all others (which makes sense, from a performance perspective).

Comment: I appreciate both your commitment to due diligence and the nice feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the update.